# None of the events are working in eclipse for JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to integrate a GUI created in JavaFX SceneBuilder into a java program. I have some buttons, sliders, and checkboxes inside of an Accordion container and the events for those objects never get handled. It always gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do I register these events? I have researched on the JavaFX website: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm and other parts of the web but I cannot find a way to get the code to catch the events.

**Here is my FXML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.westga.PictureDrawer.main.MainClass">
   <children>
      <Accordion fx:id="theMainMenu" onMouseClicked="#useMenu" prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="202.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane text="FILE">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="225.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <Button id="uploadImageButton" fx:id="uploadImageButton" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="38.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Upload" />
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="164.0" text="Open From File" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <Separator layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="183.0" />
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <TextField id="imageLinkBox" fx:id="imageLinkBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="95.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="182.0" promptText="(insert web link)">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="10.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </TextField>
                              <Button id="downloadImageButton" fx:id="downloadImageButton" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="156.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Download" />
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="164.0" text="Open From Internet" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <Separator layoutX="1.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <Button fx:id="replaceBothImages" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="386.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#replaceImages" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="159.0" text="Replace Images" />
                              <CheckBox fx:id="replaceEditedImage" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="422.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#toggleSelection" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="Replace Edited Image">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </CheckBox>
                              <ImageView id="loadedImagePreview" fx:id="loadedImagePreview" cache="true" fitHeight="163.0" fitWidth="192.0" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="201.0" pickOnBounds="true">
                                 <cursor>
                                    <Cursor fx:constant="DISAPPEAR" />
                                 </cursor>
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@no.jpg" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane text="EDIT">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Group layoutX="-5.0" layoutY="1.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="144.0" text="Pixels Per Width">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Slider fx:id="pixelsPerWidthSlider" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="36.0" onScroll="#changePixelPerSquare" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="186.0">
                                 <effect>
                                    <DropShadow spread="0.16" />
                                 </effect>
                              </Slider>
                              <Label fx:id="pixelsPerWidth" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="0">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <Group layoutX="-5.0" layoutY="1.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label id="pixelsPerLength" fx:id="pixelsPerLength" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="0">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Slider id="pixelsPerLengthSlider" fx:id="pixelsPerLengthSlider" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="97.0" onScroll="#changePixelPerSquare" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="186.0" snapToTicks="true">
                                 <effect>
                                    <DropShadow spread="0.16" />
                                 </effect>
                              </Slider>
                              <Label fx:id="pixelsPerLength" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="144.0" text="Pixels Per Length">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane text="SETTINGS">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <Group>
                                 <children>
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="jpegRadioButton" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#changeRadioButtonSetValue" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="51.0" selected="true" text="JPEG" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                       <toggleGroup>
                                          <ToggleGroup fx:id="fileType" />
                                       </toggleGroup></RadioButton>
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="pngRadioButton" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#changeRadioButtonSetValue" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="PNG" textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$fileType" />
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="gifRadioButton" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="77.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#changeRadioButtonSetValue" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="51.0" selected="true" text="GIF" textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$fileType" />
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="jpgRadioButton" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="77.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#changeRadioButtonSetValue" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="JPG" textAlignment="CENTER" toggleGroup="$fileType" />
                                 </children>
                              </Group>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="184.0" text="Default File Type for Save" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="LEADING_WORD_ELLIPSIS">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <Separator layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="Zoom">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Group layoutY="13.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="137.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Edited Image">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Slider fx:id="zoomEditedImageSlider" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="167.0" majorTickUnit="10.0" minorTickCount="1" onMouseClicked="#changeZoomLevel" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="193.0" snapToTicks="true">
                                       <effect>
                                          <DropShadow spread="0.16" />
                                       </effect>
                                    </Slider>
                                    <Label fx:id="zoomEditedImagePercentage" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                 </children>
                              </Group>
                              <Group layoutY="13.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Slider fx:id="zoomOriginalImageSlider" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="229.0" onScroll="#changeZoomLevel" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="193.0">
                                       <effect>
                                          <DropShadow spread="0.16" />
                                       </effect>
                                    </Slider>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="202.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Original Image">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="zoomOriginalImagePercentage" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="107.0" layoutY="204.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                 </children>
                              </Group>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <Separator layoutY="271.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="283.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="184.0" text="Show/Hide Image Views" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="LEADING_WORD_ELLIPSIS">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Group>
                                 <children>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutY="312.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Original Image">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <ToggleButton fx:id="toggleOriginalImageVisibilty" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="313.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#toggleOrignialImageVisibility" selected="true" text="Show/Hide" />
                                 </children>
                              </Group>
                              <Group>
                                 <children>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutY="349.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Edited Image">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <ToggleButton fx:id="toggleEditedImageVisibility" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="350.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#toggleEditedImageVisibility" text="Show/Hide" />
                                 </children>
                              </Group>
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
      </Accordion>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="202.0" prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="698.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="578.0" prefWidth="345.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="editedImage" blendMode="SRC_ATOP" fitHeight="561.0" fitWidth="322.0" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="13.0" mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@no%20takebacks.jpg" />
                     </image></ImageView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="originalImage" blendMode="SRC_ATOP" fitHeight="561.0" fitWidth="322.0" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="13.0" mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@no%20know%20answer.jpg" />
                     </image></ImageView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


public class MainClass extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Accordion theMainMenu;

    @FXML
    private TextField imageLinkBox;

    @FXML
    private Label pixelsPerWidth;

    @FXML
    private Slider pixelsPerWidthSlider;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton gifRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton jpgRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private Slider zoomEditedImageSlider;

    @FXML
    private ImageView editedImage;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton toggleOriginalImageVisibilty;

    @FXML
    private ImageView loadedImagePreview;

    @FXML
    private Label zoomOriginalImagePercentage;

    @FXML
    private Slider pixelsPerLengthSlider;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton pngRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private Button downloadImageButton;

    @FXML
    private Button replaceBothImages;

    @FXML
    private Label zoomEditedImagePercentage;

    @FXML
    private Button uploadImageButton;

    @FXML
    private Label pixelsPerLength;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton toggleEditedImageVisibility;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox replaceEditedImage;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton jpegRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private Slider zoomOriginalImageSlider;

    @FXML
    private ImageView originalImage;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup fileType;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".\\edu\\westga\\PictureDrawer\\main\\test.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void useMenu(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello8");
    }

    @FXML
    public void replaceImages(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello7");
    }

    @FXML
    public void toggleSelection(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello6");
    }

    @FXML
    public void changePixelPerSquare(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello5");
    }

    @FXML
    public void changeRadioButtonSetValue(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello4");
    }

    @FXML
    public void changeZoomLevel(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello3");
        if (event.getSource() == this.zoomEditedImageSlider) {
            this.setValueOfLabel();
        }
    }

    private void setValueOfLabel() {
        this.zoomEditedImageSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue,
                    Boolean wasChanging,
                    Boolean changing) {
                String valueString = zoomEditedImageSlider.getValue() + "%";

                if (wasChanging) {
                    zoomEditedImagePercentage.setText(valueString);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void toggleOrignialImageVisibility(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }

    @FXML
    public void toggleEditedImageVisibility(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to thank you for re-editing my question @demongolem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Problem**

In the FXML, you are using onMouseClicked="#nameOfTheMethod" and in your Controller, you have methods as

```
@FXML 
public void nameOfTheMethod(ActionEvent event) {
    //Logic 
}
```

whenever the method is Invoked, it passes a `MouseEvent`, where as your method is expecting an `ActionEvent` and therefore `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

### **Solution**

1. You can change the `onMouseClicked` for `Buttons` to `onAction` inside the FXML
2. For other controls, change the method declaration inside the controllers. Change the parameter from `ActionEvent` to `MouseEvent`

**N.B.** Move the changeListener added to `zoomEditedImageSlider` inside `setValueOfLabel()` to initialize method of the controller. Adding of listeners to controls should be done inside initialize.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will give this a try right now!